# Angular2 Cascade Animation

Tags: angular, typescript, animation, angular-animations

I'm trying to implement cascaded animation for a list of elements.

I applied the state triggers successfully - thanks to the [documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/animations.html) -, however all elements states are applied in the same time and not cascaded.

My animation:

[image: Current animation]

Expected result:

[image: Expected result]

**heroes.component.ts**

```
trigger('flyInOut', [
  state('in', style({
    transform: 'translateX(0)'
  })),
  transition('void => in', [
    style({transform: 'translateX(-100px)'}),
    animate(500)
  ]),
  transition('* => void', [
    style({transform: 'translateX(0)'}),
    animate(500)
  ])
])
```

**heroes.component.html**

```
<li *ngFor="let hero of heroes" 
    (click)="onSelect(hero)"
    [class.selected]="hero === selectedHero"
    @heroState="hero === selectedHero ? 'active' : 'inactive'"
    @flyInOut="'in'"
    >
  <span class="badge">{{hero.id}}</span> {{hero.name}}
  <button class="delete" (click)="delete(hero); $event.stopPropagation()">
    x
  </button>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is https://angular.io/api/animations/stagger.

Basically, you apply an animation to the list container (the `<ol>` in your case?) which is bound to the length of the list (or anythong else that changes when the list changes).  Then you query entering/leaving elements in the list, and use the stagger function to apply your animations in a *cascading* fashion.

As shown in the linked docs, but modified to get the effect you want (from what I can see from the gif):

```
transition('* => *', [ // each time the binding value changes
  query(':leave', [
    stagger(100, [
      animate('0.5s', style({ left: 100 }))
    ])
  ]),
  query(':enter', [
    style({ left: -100 }),
    stagger(100, [
      animate('0.5s', style({ left: 0 }))
    ])
  ])
])
```